# How can I access Blackfish for Windows over JDBC?

Tags: java, windows, delphi, jdbc, blackfish

For Blackfish for Windows which is included in Delphi 2009 I would like to write a Java client and use a JDBC connection. If I understand correctly, this is supported: http://edn.embarcadero.com/de/article/36851

> The database clients and servers are
>   interchangeable. Windows clients can
>   connect to Java servers and Java
>   clients can connect to Windows
>   servers.

Where can I find the JDBC driver for Blackfish?

Many thanks for the download link for the JDBC driver. **License question**: Do I have to purchase a Blackfish version for Java if I only want to use the included JDBC driver to connect with an existing Blackfish for Windows database server? Or can I use the JDBC driver from the trial version free of charge?

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC Drivers are located in the Blackfish SQL lib installation directory.

check theses files

- **jds.jar** Local JDBC database connectivity
- **jdsremote.jar** Remote JDBC thin client database connectivity

You can read theses articles

- [Blackfish SQL Establishing Connections](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/bfsql/deployjds_xml.html)
- [Blackfish SQL Deploying Blackfish SQL Database Applications](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/bfsql/deployjds_xml.html)

**UPDATE**

You can download and install The Blackfish SQL 8 for Java Trial (Windows Version) wich includes the JDBC Drivers from [here](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/blackfish_sql).

[image]

Comment: Thes files are not included in Delphi 2009. Blackfish however is installed and running as a service. Is there a way to download these files?

Comment: Just checked my D2010 install, and these files aren't included in it, either. What SKU are you using (Pro, Enterprise, Architect)?

Comment: Checked that they are not in Pro and will check Enterprise tomorrow.

Comment: @Ken and @mjustin, JDBC drivers are not included with Delphi, these are within Blackfish SQL for Java that can be downloaded from this location https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/blackfish_sql